# How to create a SocialMedia TimeLine with JSON and PHP?

Tags: php, html, json, youtube, instagram

I am creating a website where I like to get a timeline of my socialmedia accounts. Currently, I have 2 `PHP` classes (`Youtube-plugin`, `Instagram-Plugin`)  that get me `JSON` Files of each network.

```
class PersonalinstagramPlugin{
    public $myAccesToken;
    public $myUsername;
    public $myUserID;

public function __construct($accesToken,$Username) {
    $this->myAccesToken = $accesToken;
    $this->myUsername = $Username;
    $this->myUserID = $this->curlConnect("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=" . $this->myUsername . "&access_token=" . $this->myAccesToken)->data[0]->id; }


public function curlConnect($api_url)
{
    $connection_c = curl_init(); // initializing
    curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url ); // API URL to connect
    curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 ); // return the result, do not print
    curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20 );
    $json_return = curl_exec( $connection_c ); // connect and get json data
    curl_close( $connection_c ); // close connection
    return json_decode( $json_return ); // decode and return
}
public function getLatestPosts()
{
     $response = $this->curlConnect("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/".$this->myUserID."/media/recent?access_token=".$this->myAccesToken);
     return $response;
}
```

For a the `youtube` plugin it is the same. 
What is the best way to combine the data you get from each plugin `(JSON)` and combine them in one timeline sorted by date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking this from an OO approach, I would suggest you look into inheritance. The result you get from youtube and the result you get from instagram likely have some common fields such as an ID, postdate, last modified and content. Create an object that can store these common fields and call it something like SocialMediaPost. This can be used to represent every single social media post.

You can then create 2 objects specific to each network that contain the custom fields and these classes can inherit from the SocialMediaPost class. You can parse the json to the custom objects and store them in an array. Using a loop you can then cast each post to the base type and order them by the post date or something like that.